# Create a VIEW that spans 3 tables

Tags: mysql, performance, view, query-performance

Sorry if the title is not clear - feel free to improve.

Here are 3 tables (not all data is relevant to the question):

```
CREATE TABLE `content` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `community_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'The community for whom this URL has special rules',
  `url_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'The URL that has special rules',
  `question_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `banned` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Flags if a URL is banned from the community',
  `featured` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'If this article is to be featured on this site',
  `slider_image` tinytext,
  `weight` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `create_time` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `content_url_unique` (`community_id`,`url_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `content_question_unique` (`community_id`,`question_id`),
  KEY `community_index` (`community_id`),
  KEY `content_url_idx` (`url_id`),
  KEY `content_community_idx` (`community_id`),
  KEY `content_question_idx` (`question_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `content_community` FOREIGN KEY (`community_id`) REFERENCES `community` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `content_question` FOREIGN KEY (`question_id`) REFERENCES `question` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `content_url` FOREIGN KEY (`url_id`) REFERENCES `url` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=186 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `url_tag` (
  `url_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'The URL to be tagged',
  `tag_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'The tag the url refers to',
  PRIMARY KEY (`url_id`,`tag_id`),
  KEY `FK_urltag_url_idx` (`url_id`),
  KEY `FK_urltag_tag_idx` (`tag_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_urltag_tag` FOREIGN KEY (`tag_id`) REFERENCES `tag` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_urltag_url` FOREIGN KEY (`url_id`) REFERENCES `url` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Allows to tag URLs';

CREATE TABLE `question_tag` (
  `question_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `tag_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`question_id`,`tag_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `question_tag` (`question_id`,`tag_id`),
  KEY `fk_questiontag_question_idx` (`question_id`),
  KEY `fk_questiontag_tag_idx` (`tag_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_questiontag_question` FOREIGN KEY (`question_id`) REFERENCES `question` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_questiontag_tag` FOREIGN KEY (`tag_id`) REFERENCES `tag` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='The tags associated with a given question';
```

Note that Content is meant to have either a `url_id`, or a `question_id` - not both.
I need a way to connect a Content ID to a Tag ID. I was thinking of creating a VIEW, and here are 2 possibilities I came up with so far.

Option 1:

```
(SELECT content.id AS content_id, url_tag.tag_id AS tag_id
FROM url_tag, content
WHERE url_tag.url_id = content.url_id)
UNION
(SELECT content.id AS content_id, question_tag.tag_id AS tag_id
FROM question_tag, content
WHERE question_tag.question_id = content.question_id)
```

Option 2:

```
SELECT content.id AS content_id, COALESCE(url_tag.tag_id, question_tag.tag_id) AS tag_id
FROM `content`
LEFT JOIN url_tag ON content.url_id = url_tag.url_id
LEFT JOIN question_tag ON content.question_id = question_tag.question_id WHERE COALESCE(url_tag.tag_id, question_tag.tag_id) IS NOT NULL
```

My question is which one is the better approach (or if there is one better)?

Note also that currently some Contents are not tagged at all.

Bonus challenge: a VIEW that connects content_id straight to category_id

```
CREATE TABLE `category_tag` (
  `category_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `tag_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`,`tag_id`),
  KEY `FK_categorytag_category_idx` (`category_id`),
  KEY `FK_categorytag_tag_idx` (`tag_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_categorytag_category` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `category` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_categorytag_tag` FOREIGN KEY (`tag_id`) REFERENCES `tag` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: It's my understanding that views in MySQL are not materialized.  As such, they really offer little value.

Comment: Well I would start by never using implicit joins under any circumstances. That is a SQL Antipattern.

Comment: @AlainCollins A view is a stored query by definition.  Materialized views are a rather different story.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not really a strong case here for doing this with views.

Of options 1 and 2, option 2 is the only option that is likely to be usable on data of any size, because of the [different algorithms MySQL uses for processing views](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/view-algorithms.html), and the strengths vs. limitations of each.

Unless explicitly declared otherwise, MySQL uses the `MERGE` algorithm whenever possible, which essentially makes the view into an alias for a more complicated query.  This provides some optimizations especially with the use of indexes in the underlying tables when interpreting the `WHERE` clause in the outer query.

```
SELECT * FROM view_option_2 WHERE content_id = 500;
```

I don't see a reason why `MERGE` could not be used with this view definition, so the server should process the query above as though you had sent this:

```
SELECT content.id AS content_id, 
       COALESCE(url_tag.tag_id, question_tag.tag_id) AS tag_id
  FROM `content`
  LEFT JOIN url_tag ON content.url_id = url_tag.url_id
  LEFT JOIN question_tag ON content.question_id = question_tag.question_id 
 WHERE content.id = 500
   AND COALESCE(url_tag.tag_id, question_tag.tag_id) IS NOT NULL
```

This could reasonably be expected to use the primary key on `content` and the leftmost column of the primary key of `utl_tag` and `question_tag`.  It seems like a nice, tidy, well-indexed query.

On the other hand, if Option 1 were used for a view definition, the server would not be able to use the `MERGE` algorithm, because of the `UNION`... so the server would use the other algorithm, `TEMPTABLE`, and construct a temporary table and fill it with the union of the two queries and then return only the rows specified by your where clause by eliminating non-matching rows from the temporary table.  But the point you don't want to overlook here is that the temporary table could contain every possible row without regard to the `WHERE` in your outer query.

You don't have to specify an `ALGORITHM` when you define a view, and if you don't, then it defaults to `UNDEFINED` which allows the server to choose.  One advantage of specifying an algorithm is that you always know which one will be used.  Extra bonus, you get a warning if you ask for `MERGE` and it can't be done.  Merge also doesn't work if there are no tables in the view, so here's a simple example:

```
mysql> CREATE ALGORITHM=MERGE VIEW test_view AS SELECT UUID_SHORT() AS a_big_number;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.05 sec)
```

We didn't get an error but we did get a warning.

```
mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                                       |
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1354 | View merge algorithm can't be used here for now (assumed undefined algorithm) |
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

This is, however, a perfectly legitimate and working view, that returns a different number each time:

```
mysql> select * from test_view;
+---------------------+
| a_big_number        |
+---------------------+
| 2184556849028661248 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Define your view with `ALGORITHM=MERGE` and if the server doesn't like it, then that's not a good candidate for a view in this application.

Note, though, that this doesn't mean the `TEMPTABLE` algorithm isn't without its benefits also... but if you are going to `SELECT` from your view `WHERE` some condition applies to the fields in the underlying tables, `TEMPTABLE` prevents those conditions from "pushing through" the view definition.  Instead, they're applied to the result after the temporary table is derived, and of course that temporary table has no indexes.

---

Your "bonus" does not seem unusually complicated, either.

Take the Option 2 query and modify it:

```
SELECT content.id AS content_id, 
       COALESCE(url_tag.tag_id, question_tag.tag_id) AS tag_id,
       category_tag.category_id
  FROM `content`
  LEFT JOIN url_tag ON content.url_id = url_tag.url_id
  LEFT JOIN question_tag ON content.question_id = question_tag.question_id 
  LEFT JOIN category_tag on category_tag.tag_id = COALESCE(url_tag.tag_id, question_tag.tag_id)
 WHERE COALESCE(url_tag.tag_id, question_tag.tag_id) IS NOT NULL
```

If you don't want to eliminate untagged content, remove the `WHERE` clause.

To select for a specific content.id, put that in the `WHERE` clause.

If you get duplicate categories because of the relationships between category and tag then you'll need `SELECT DISTINCT` but don't put that inside the view, because that isn't compatible with `MERGE` either.

Comment: "There's not really a strong case here for doing this with views" - I'm doing this simply to make coding simpler, instead of storing this query.

Comment: I went with Option 2. Using "explain" also made it seem better to use option 2.